# Filling an array with arrays that contain doubles

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a class assignment where we can only use arrays and no Collection classes to read a text file and fill an array with information from the text file. the file ArrayData.txt is the information bellow.
The file is formatted in this way:

```
3                 //First line states how many sets are in the file
2                 //Next line:there are x numbers in the set
10.22  567.98     //Next Line states the doubles that are in the set
//The pattern continues from there
1                 // x numbers in the next set
20.55             // Double in the set
3
20.55 2.34 100.97
```

My issue is filling the initial array with an array, then filling the second array with the doubles.

Essentially, I want it to look like this:

```
initArray[0]=> smallArray[2]={10.22,5.67.98} 
initArray[1]=> smallArray[1]={20.55} 
initArray[2]=> smallArray[3]={20.55,2.34,100.97}
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
    public static double[] largeArray;
    public static double[] insideArray;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

     String fileInputName  = "ArrayData.txt";
     Scanner sc = null;           
     try {
         sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileInputName)));
         while (sc.hasNextLine()) {                    


             int i = sc.nextInt();
             largeArray= new double[i];
             for(int x=0; x<i;x++)
             {
                 int z = sc.nextInt();

                  insideArray= new double[z];
                for(int y=0; y<z; y++)
                {
                    insideArray[z]=sc.nextDouble();
                }
             }
         }
     }
     catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     finally {
         if (sc != null)
             sc.close(); 
     }  
}
```

First off, does this logic even make sense? Secondly, I keep getting an array out of bounds error, so I know something is right, I'm just not sure where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `while`. You want the body to execute only once. Line breaks at the end of the file may cause it to run again and then there will be no `nextInt()`. If you want to support empty files, make it an `if`.

Secondly, `insideArray[z] = ...` should be `insideArray[y] = ...`

Finally, `largeArray` should be an array of arrays `double[][]` (a so called jagged array) and you want to assign `insideArray` to the according place after filling it.

Comment: This may be a dumb question but how do you assign insideArray in the right place of largeArray? Would it be like largeArray[i][insideArray]

Comment: `largeArray[x] = insideArray`. Or you may directly work with `largeArray[x]` and not use `insideArray` at all.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This fixed everything!